# Is there an OS X equivalent to the web debugging proxy Fiddler?

Tags: software-recommendation, software, development, proxy

I do web development on Windows for my day job, and I rely a lot on [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), which is web debugging proxy.  What is an equivalent tool for OS X?

Comment: Have you checked out the developer tools in Safari and Chrome, or the Firebug extension for Firefox?  All three offer the ability to monitor HTTP traffic, and all can monitor a specific tab instead of monitoring HTTP traffic systemwide.

Comment: What specifically do you use fiddler for? I use the development tools built into webkit to do everything I've ever needed for debugging HTTP. Safari's development menu is slightly better than Chrome's, but they're almost identical. Either one gives you various different ways to view all network activity in a browser tab.

Comment: I started out developing c# desktop apps that talk to webservices via HTTP and using fiddler to debug, so it's partly just habit.  Also, I like the ability to manually craft and replay requests, which as far as I can tell is absent from the browsers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I use [CharlesProxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), and while it isn't as scriptable as Fiddler, it does the job. And with single license key, you can run it on all OSes (it's written in Java).

My needs were little different when I needed it ... I used it to debug webdav connections or to debug http communication between servers.

Answer (score 24):

Stuff that's Free:

- [Burp Suite](http://portswigger.net/burp/)
- [WiireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/)
- [ParosProxy](http://www.parosproxy.org/)
- [NetTool](http://nettool.sourceforge.net/)
- [LiveHTTPHeaders](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/)
- [Safari WebInspector Network Tab](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/safari/developer-tools.html)
- [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/)

Stuff that Costs:

- $1.99 -  [HTTPClient](http://ditchnet.org/httpclient/)
- $15.00 - [HTTP Scoop](http://www.tuffcode.com/)
- $50.00 - [CharlesProxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)

Comment: Good list. See also Cellist below - it's on the Mac app store. It's a proxy, $5.

Answer (score 8):

These are both free and haven't been mentioned so far.  I found that both of these are far superior to the X11 Wireshark.

- [Cocoa Packet Analyzer](http://www.tastycocoabytes.com/cpa/)
- [Packet Peeper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/packetpeeper/)

Comment: Wireshark is SUPER POWERFUL. But not easy to use.

Answer (score 6):

http://mitmproxy.org/ is text-based tool, but does a great job.  For any http-speaking app you want to analyse, and even modify and replay requests.

Answer (score 3):

Fiddler now has an [Alpha build](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/mono) based on Mono.

Comment: Now in beta buld.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to see HTTP traffic, try [Cellist](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cellist/id897814548?mt=12).

Comment: Works pretty well. Super basic.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Tamper](http://dutzi.github.io/tamper)

It's a Chrome extension that lets you view and modify HTTP requests in the current tab's scope

Answer (score 1):

Try [Proxyman](https://proxyman.io), which is exclusively built for macOS.

- Easy to use and set up the certificates on mac/iOS/Android
- All advanced tools: Map Local, Map Remote, Breakpoint, Scripting, ...
- Active development and [bug/feature tracker](https://github.com/ProxymanApp/Proxyman)
- It's a premium app without time limit

Disclaimer: I'm a creator of Proxyman. Just come here to suggest a better alternative to boost productivity. Hope you enjoy the app!

Answer (score 0):

[ZAP Attack proxy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project) from OWASP is an excellent OpenSource alternative.

The already mentioned [Burp](http://portswigger.net/burp/) is also excellent but the paid version is much better than the free version.

I use both for work.

Answer (score 0):

[Captor](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/captor-http-analyzer/id1100708036?mt=12), available on mac app store

It's a native app , can capture HTTP/HTTPS just like CharlesProxy.

Answer (score -1):

There's a mac version now via mono.
Install Fiddler on Mac OSX
About the App

App name: Fiddler
App description: fiddler (App: Fiddler.app)
App website: http://www.telerik.com/fiddler
Install the App

Press Command+Space and type Terminal and press enter/return key.
Run in Terminal app:
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null ; brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask 2> /dev/null
and press enter/return key. Wait for the command to finish.
Run:
brew cask install fiddler
Done! You can now use Fiddler.